# how to fix position vertically and absolute horizontally for a division

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to fix header vertically and absolute horizontally. I am using the following codes.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="header_position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

body tag

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
$("#headerpos").css("margin-left", 0-$(document).scrollLeft());
});



#headerpos{
position:fixed;
border-top:8px solid #8DC540;
background:#1E415B;
width:956px;
padding-bottom:7px;
margin:auto;
z-index:100;
 }
```

I tried using class attrb in `div` as well as id attrb

```
.header{
position:fixed;
border-top:8px solid #8DC540;
background:#1E415B;
width:956px;
padding-bottom:7px;
margin:auto;
z-index:100;
 }
```

Also tried by removing `margin:auto`;

I saw this all from the link [Position a Div "Fixed" Vertically and "Absolute" Horizontally within a "Position:Relative" Container Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327093/position-a-div-fixed-vertically-and-absolute-horizontally-within-a-position)

But it is not working and in Chrome if I go to inspect element I see an error:

> Uncaught Reference error: $ is not defined (at line 1)

Please help. It's very important.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery in the head of your page like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="header_position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, be sure to wrap your jQuery in a document ready call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        $("#headerpos").css("margin-left", 0 - $(document).scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

Comment: not getting the $ not defined error now, but scroll left right not working it fixed. on scroll left right below data is getting scrolled, not header.

Answer (score 0):

If `$` is not defined, you'll need jQuery. Just include

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before the other script.

I also recommend putting both `script` tags at the bottom of the page to make it load faster.

Comment: not getting the $ not defined error now, but scroll left right not working it fixed. on scroll left right below data is getting scrolled, not header.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using fixed positioning in css, you don't need js to centeralign a div horizontally.
try this.

```
.header{
   position:fixed;
   border-top:8px solid #8DC540;
   background:#1E415B;
   width:956px;
   padding-bottom:7px;
   margin-left:-478px;
   left:50%;
   z-index:100;
}
```