# Position a button such that it won't scroll with contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```css
pre[class*="language-"] {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#copybutton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  border: 0px transparent;
  font-size: 0.725rem;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://prismjs.com/themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://prismjs.com/prism.js"></script>
<pre class="language-js">
  <button id="copybutton">Copy</button>
  <code>const name = "" //a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long </code>
</pre>
```

I want to position the button such that when the user scrolls the code horizontally, the button should not move prom its place. But when the user scrolls the page (not the code) it should move. CSS and JS answers appreciated. Please don't answer in jQuery.

Comment: Also see: [Position a Div “Fixed” Vertically and “Absolute” Horizontally within a “Position:Relative” Container Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327093/position-a-div-fixed-vertically-and-absolute-horizontally-within-a-position)

Comment: Add an additional wrapper around the `pre` element, and put the button _outside_ of the `pre` …?

Comment: @CBroe add an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a wrapper `div`, make *that* relative instead of the `pre` itself, and take the button out of `pre`.

```css
.code-display-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

pre[class*="language-"] {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#copybutton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  border: 0px transparent;
  font-size: 0.725rem;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://prismjs.com/themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://prismjs.com/prism.js"></script>

foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>

<div class="code-display-wrapper">
  <button id="copybutton">Copy</button>
  <pre class="language-js">
    <code>const name = "" //a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long </code>
  </pre>
</div>

foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```css
    pre[class*="language-"] {
      top: 0;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    #copybutton {
      position: fixed;
      right: 5em;
      top: 1.5em;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
      border: 0px transparent;
      font-size: 0.725rem;
      padding: 3px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #ebebeb;
      transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://prismjs.com/themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://prismjs.com/prism.js"></script>
    <pre class="language-js">
      <button id="copybutton">Copy</button>
      <code>const name = "" //a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long </code>
    </pre>
```

Comment: button is not visible